# Errors while restoring mariadb/mysql dump in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, docker-compose, mysqldump

I'm running mariadb in a docker container. I want to backup and restore using a sql dump.

I created the database for use with wordpress, and created just one test page. I installed phpmyadmin to the same database.

I created a backup like this:

```
mysqldump \
  --all-databases \
  --add-drop-database --add-drop-table \
  --user=root --password=password \
  > seed.sql
```

Then I mounted the `seed.sql` dump in `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
volumes:
  - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql/
  - ./seed_data/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Then I deleted the `mariadb_data` volume and container, and restarted the container. The database read the seed script, and seemed to restore the database.

But, the logs show this:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found.

I got the same error with a mysql container. What did I do wrong? Did I create the backup correctly?

---

UPDATE

I just discovered that this only occurs when I use the database for wordpress. When I don't install wordpress into the database, and backup and restore it, I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* dump tables in `mysql`, `information_schema`, `performance_schema` -- they are system tables.

Comment: Thanks. All the official examples use `mysqldump --all-databases` - are you saying that is incorrect? What do I do instead?

Comment: @lonix - Look in the dump file to see what was dumped.